# Vlookup inside a Vlookup looking for multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to make a box shown below, all white boxes are for users to enter data, e.g. a start and end date then a tray end type, these will then return how much of that tray end has been used in the set dates in the cell H25.

[image]

This will then need to look at another table called **product** to find every time the selected tray end type appears, from this i should be able to find all products that use it. A sample of this table is shown below.

[image]

Then after this it would need to find all of those products in another table called **Waste** within the set dates (Date Packed column) and add up the Printed Amount column.

[image]

I already have a similar formula:

```
=SUMIFS(Waste[Cost],Waste[Date Packed],">=" & G12,Waste[Date Packed],"<=" & H12, Waste[Product], "=" &H13)
```

This one is used to add up the cost column for a set date range / product name. So I would guess it would be similar to this but just with an extra Vlookup in as it is needing to search from 2 tables where as the previous formula only uses one.

Thank You in advance for any help / support.
 - Tom

Edit:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b6xgbk2zuklg5bp/Tray%20End%20Recording.xlsx?dl=0

I have attached a sample, essentially with the attached, you could insert the date 26/10/18 into the start and end date boxes, then insert **Tesco** into the tray end type box which would add the printed amount column for all products that use Tesco labels, in this case this should work out as 2,250.

Comment: It looks like a rather large task. Not sure I really understood it all. I believe it would be helpful if you could upload a sample of this workbook with dummy values and an example of what the output should be. You can hardcode the links for the example as `=A10` just to populate the table and we will be able to see the pattern

Comment: @Andreas I have added this information, see edit at bottom of original post.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? You have a requirement to join data from multiple tables, so [tag:PowerPivot] would be your best solution, if you're using Excel 2010 or later.

Comment: @Olly Thank you, i am using 2010 so will have to look into Power Pivot, not heard of it before.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use power pivot, I would suggest adding a new column to your 'Waste' table, to look up the Label Type from 'Products'. If you cannot or do not want to update the 'Waste' table, then you could potentially create a copy, say 'Waste2' on a separate (hidden?) tab, by a direct reference to the Waste table and add a column there. Then you can do the 'sumif' using the new column.

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing it that way so for now i have settled with an extra column that has been minimized to find the label type on the Waste table, which i can then use for the sumif statement, this works perfectly. I will continue to experiment with Power pivot for a slightly cleaner solution.

Thank You!